# Java Spring Error: Error creating bean with name : nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

First off I'd like to say I'm new to Java coding and will try my best to explain my problem.

I'm working on a project in Eclipse using the Spring framework and Gradle. It's early in the coding process, but I'm trying to run my program in the console to test and make sure I have no errors.  However, when I run as a Java project I keep encountering this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'listRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.elevenfifty.shopping.beans.ShoppingList
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.elevenfifty.shopping.Application.main(Application.java:10) [bin/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.elevenfifty.shopping.beans.ShoppingList
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.elevenfifty.shopping.beans.ShoppingList
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:152) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:99) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted
```

It appears that my problem is somewhere in my ShoppingListController, ShoppingListRepository, and my ShoppingList bean.  I'll post the code to those below.

ShoppingList bean:

```
    package org.packagename.shopping.beans;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.packagename.shopping.DateTimeOffset;

public class ShoppingList {
    //adding in variables per the TDD
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private int userId;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    //created custom class to create a DateTimeOffset since it is a SQL only type of variable
    private DateTimeOffset createdUtc;
    private DateTimeOffset modifiedUtc;

    //getters setters and hash coding and equals for variables
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset getCreatedUtc() {
        return createdUtc;
    }

    public void setCreatedUtc(DateTimeOffset createdUtc) {
        this.createdUtc = createdUtc;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset getModifiedUtc() {
        return modifiedUtc;
    }

    public void setModifiedUtc(DateTimeOffset modifiedUtc) {
        this.modifiedUtc = modifiedUtc;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((createdUtc == null) ? 0 : createdUtc.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((modifiedUtc == null) ? 0 : modifiedUtc.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + userId;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ShoppingList other = (ShoppingList) obj;
        if (color == null) {
            if (other.color != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
            return false;
        if (createdUtc == null) {
            if (other.createdUtc != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!createdUtc.equals(other.createdUtc))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (modifiedUtc == null) {
            if (other.modifiedUtc != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!modifiedUtc.equals(other.modifiedUtc))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (userId != other.userId)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

ShoppingListController:

```
    package org.packagename.shopping.controller;

import org.elevenfifty.shopping.repository.ShoppingListRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ShoppingListController {

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingListRepository listRepo;

    @GetMapping("/ShoppingList")
    public String ShoppingList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("Shopping List", listRepo.findAll());
        return "Shopping_List";
    }
}
```

ShoppingListRepository:

```
    package org.packagename.shopping.controller;

import org.packagenameenter code here.shopping.repository.ShoppingListRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ShoppingListController {

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingListRepository listRepo;

    @GetMapping("/ShoppingList")
    public String ShoppingList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("Shopping List", listRepo.findAll());
        return "Shopping_List";
    }
}
```

Comment: ShoppingList should've an Entity annotation.

Comment: You posted the controller twice and miss the repository

Comment: Please fix your question to make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is written in your output:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.elevenfifty.shopping.beans.ShoppingList

Your class `ShoppingList` Should have an Annotation `@Component` to be recognized as bean. Otherwise Spring just doesn't see it as Bean and thus tells you so

Answer (score 0):

The error means that ShoppingList is not present in your dependency injection container. you need to define your ShoppingList bean in application context.